# Click notification action button programmatically

Tags: android, notifications, accessibilityservice

How can I click a notification action button programmatically (another application notif, not my)? 
I can click a normal button by using the button.performClick() method.
I have accessibility service to listen to incoming notification (and Notification Service listener to android 5.0+),
So,there is any way to do that?

For example, click Turn on battery saver or share/delete pragmatically

[image: ...]

[image]

Comment: No one knows how?

Comment: did you find any solution

Comment: i think that it is not easy

Comment: Only using accessibility service..

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle this via `Accessibility Service` or `NotificationListenerService`

after that when you get `Notification` class, you can do it by this function:

```
sbn.notification.actions[0].actionIntent.send()
```

Comment: I know that I can do it using Accessibility Service, looking for something else..

Comment: Just look the answer clearly, I said you can do this with accessibility and `notificationListenerService` , there is no way rather than these two. too funny I answer and get negative for that!